# java error when trying to fetch node from json response

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am trying to retrieve details from a node within a json path using rest assured and java. However I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/groovy/io/StringBuilderWriter
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseObject(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:105)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:83)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:949)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:984)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:951)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1031)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
    at uk.co.hermes.cucumber.utils.xxx.postAccessToken(xxx.java:86)
    at uk.co.hermes.cucumber.utils.xxx.unblockUser(xxx.java:27)
```

I know the issue is with this line in the code:

```
String token = jsonPathEvaluator.get("token");
```

How can this be fixed?

```
public void postAccessToken(){

    RestAssured.baseURI  = "https://xxx";

    JSONObject requestJsonBodyParams = new JSONObject();
    requestJsonBodyParams.put("test", "xxx");



    Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .contentType(jsonContentType).
                    body(requestJsonBodyParams.toString()).
                    when().
                    post("/");

    Assert.assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 200);

    JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
    String token = jsonPathEvaluator.get("token");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have all the dependencies installed in the runtime environment? May worth a look to your build tool. Also, check the runtime environment whether you have those jars installed.

Comment: Error is more of a missing dependency. Can you provide the dependency tree of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same error and after deep diving in POM.xml i figured out there were multiple groovy dependency however removing this :

Just worked like a charm. I am not sure if that would help but yes try removing multiples groovy dependency.

Comment: "<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.12</version>
</dependency>"

Answer (score 5):

My answer assumes that you are using Maven/Gradle. Please let us know if this is not the case.

This error is a sign of a missing dependency on the classpath, alternatively a version crash. Generally, this should not happen as dependencies you use should include transitive dependencies to its own dependencies. As for restassured, it contains a dependency to groovy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, there might be several potential reasons for this happening:

Either you have excluded the transitive dependency to groovy from your restassured dependency, or you have a dependency to groovy with a different version than what restassured expects (one where the class in question is not available). A third option is that you have multiple dependencies depending on groovy, with different versions.

If you are using maven, a quick way to check is through this command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.codehaus.groovy
```

If you can try this, please post the result.

Also, let us know which version of RestAssured you are using.

**Update:**

From your dependency:tree output you can see that there are several groovy versions in play here. The 2.5.6 I guess is added as an attempt to fix this, **you can remove that** as it only gives you a version crash.

But, the good parts:

You have two dependencies:

```
net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.5.2
net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:2.0.48
```

These each have groovy dependencies, but for widely different versions, 2.4.11 and 2.5.5, respectively. This leads to a version crash, as code that expects 2.5.5 suddenly has to work with 2.4.11.

The class that is missing was added to the code base after version 2.4.11, so you have code that expects this class to be there, but it is not.

There are two ways of fixing this:

Either add a explicit depenency to groovy, as this will override the version of any transitive dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

This is NOT the best way to fix it though, since you will still have a dependency that is assuming that you are using version 2.4.11.

The proper way to fix this is to align the version of the two mentioned dependencies:

```
net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.5.2
net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:2.0.48
```

Without knowing any details about this framework, I would assume that you should use the same version for these two dependencies.

Update #2:

A quick google search shows that these two dependencies seem to follow the same versioning scheme. To sum up, **either upgrade serentiy-core to 2.0.48, or downgrade serenity-rest-assured to 1.5.2. Also, remove your dependency to groovy-all.**

Comment: Hi, I still get the same issue but I have posted the result in the question based on the mvn command you supplied to me. Using Rest-Assured - 3.1.1. I'm going to update to 3.3.0 and see what happens in the mean time

Comment: Perfect, that has fixed it. Thank you very much and I will award you bounty once available which is in 20 hours

Comment: @BruceyBandit did you forget? ;)